# How to change the timezone of my latex document irrespective of my computer time zone using datetime2?

Tags: datetime

I want to change the timezone format (say, I want to use always GMT-3 timezone). I am using the [datetime2](https://ctan.org/pkg/datetime2?lang=en) package. Do I need to use the following command as mentioned in the [manual](http://ftp.lyx.org/pub/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/datetime2/datetime2.pdf)?

`\DTMdisplayzone{〈TZh〉}{〈TZm〉}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `datetime2` package has a library for performing calculations on times and dates which can be loaded with `\usepackage[calc]{datetime2}`. This library provides two functions to convert from and to Zulu time (UTC+0). With these functions you can do a three-step approach: first convert the local time to Zulu time, second convert the Zulu time to the timezone you want to show, and third actually show the result of step two in the requested timezone.

In the MWE below I defined two new commands, one for converting to arbitrary time zones with two arguments for the offset and the reverse offset, and one shortcut command with the arguments pre-filled for Central European Summer Time (which is a bit odd since it is not summer at the moment, but in any case it is UTC+2, so Finland, the Baltics, most of the Balkan countries, some Middle Eastern countries, Egypt, Libya).

MWE:

```
\documentclass[en-MT]{article}
\usepackage[calc,useregional]{datetime2}
\begin{document}
\DTMsetstyle{en-MT-numeric}

\newcommand{\DTMtznow}[2]{%
% store current time in object 'now'
\DTMsavenow{now}%
% convert current time to UTC+0
\DTMtozulu{now}{currzulu}%
% add requested timezone offset to zulu time
\DTMsaveaszulutime{currcest}{\DTMfetchyear{currzulu}}{\DTMfetchmonth{currzulu}}{\DTMfetchday{currzulu}}{\DTMfetchhour{currzulu}}{\DTMfetchminute{currzulu}}{\DTMfetchsecond{currzulu}}{#2}{00}%
% display zulu+offset in requested timezone (= reverse offset)
\DTMdisplay{\DTMfetchyear{currcest}}{\DTMfetchmonth{currcest}}{\DTMfetchday{currcest}}{}{\DTMfetchhour{currcest}}{\DTMfetchminute{currcest}}{\DTMfetchsecond{currcest}}{#1}{00}%
}
% shortcut command for central european summer time (UTC+2)
\newcommand{\DTMcestnow}{\DTMtznow{+02}{-02}}

in current timezone: \DTMnow

in CEST: \DTMcestnow
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: @PoreyS indeed en-MT is just for styling. The +02 and -02 are because you need to subtract to _store_ the time in the requested timezone as UTC+0, and then provide the reverse timezone parameter to _show_ the calculated UTC+0 time in the requested timezone again. It's a bit of a roundabout way, the datetime2 package is much more aimed at formatting dates and times than at calculating. For 30 minutes difference you should extend the command to accept two extra arguments #3 and #4 and use them instead of the two `00` values (right after the current #1 and #2).