# Set specific Time Zone, WRT local time

Tags: datetime2

I am trying to adapt code, from a [prior relevant answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/634977/134641), which I copy below:

```
\documentclass[en-MT]{article}
\usepackage[calc,useregional]{datetime2}
\begin{document}
\DTMsetstyle{en-MT-numeric}

\newcommand{\DTMtznow}[2]{%
% store current time in object 'now'
\DTMsavenow{now}%
% convert current time to UTC+0
\DTMtozulu{now}{currzulu}%
% add requested timezone offset to zulu time
\DTMsaveaszulutime{currcest}{\DTMfetchyear{currzulu}}{\DTMfetchmonth{currzulu}}{\DTMfetchday{currzulu}}{\DTMfetchhour{currzulu}}{\DTMfetchminute{currzulu}}{\DTMfetchsecond{currzulu}}{#2}{00}%
% display zulu+offset in requested timezone (= reverse offset)
\DTMdisplay{\DTMfetchyear{currcest}}{\DTMfetchmonth{currcest}}{\DTMfetchday{currcest}}{}{\DTMfetchhour{currcest}}{\DTMfetchminute{currcest}}{\DTMfetchsecond{currcest}}{#1}{00}%
}
% shortcut command for central european summer time (UTC+2)
\newcommand{\DTMcestnow}{\DTMtznow{+02}{-02}}

in current timezone: \DTMnow

in CEST: \DTMcestnow
\end{document}
```

The above code produces:

[image: Screenshot of the PDF output, generated from the LaTeX compilation of the above code.]

However, this is problematic: I am in Montréal and this is off by 5 hours. This occurs in spite of my local time (per my machine's clock) being accurate.

How do I set the specific time zone to match the time in Montréal? Or even simpler, can I just make it read the time on my computer? (You can ignore the CEST time, as it is not related to my question.)

Comment: Honestly I don't understand your question. The code you refer to from the previous question works fine, and is made to show the offset between GMT (or UTC) and Central European time which is two hours ahead (CEST). 

If you want to get the 5 hour offset (since Montreal is 5 hours behind GMT) and print both, you have to rebuild the command that calculates the time difference (`\DTMtznow`) so that instead of adding 2, it subtracts 5 hours. Or you can do a hack like this: `\newcommand{\DTMestnow}{\DTMtznow{-05}{-07}}`, but it's not the best way to do it.

Comment: To me it sounds like you just want to use `\DTMnow`..?

Answer (score -1):

In the end, the following code solves my problem:

```
\documentclass[en-MT]{article}
\usepackage[calc,useregional]{datetime2}
\begin{document}
\DTMsetstyle{en-MT-numeric}

\newcommand{\DTMtznow}[2]{%
% store current time in object 'now'
\DTMsavenow{now}%
% convert current time to UTC+0
\DTMtozulu{now}{currzulu}%
% add requested timezone offset to zulu time
\DTMsaveaszulutime{currcest}{\DTMfetchyear{currzulu}}{\DTMfetchmonth{currzulu}}{\DTMfetchday{currzulu}}{\DTMfetchhour{currzulu}}{\DTMfetchminute{currzulu}}{\DTMfetchsecond{currzulu}}{#2}{00}%
% display zulu+offset in requested timezone (= reverse offset)
\DTMdisplay{\DTMfetchyear{currcest}}{\DTMfetchmonth{currcest}}{\DTMfetchday{currcest}}{}{\DTMfetchhour{currcest}}{\DTMfetchminute{currcest}}{\DTMfetchsecond{currcest}}{#1}{00}
}
% shortcut command for central european summer time (UTC+2)
\newcommand{\DTMestnow}{\DTMtznow{-05}{+05}}

in Montreal: \DTMestnow
\end{document}
```

This gives:

[image]